# Android Huawei Ideos X3 (U8510) : Restoring static boot logo and animation from ClockWorkMod backup?

Tags: android, root, recovery, cyanogenmod

I have a rooted (and unlocked) Huawei Ideos X3 (U8510). I have complete backups of the stock ROM using ClockWordMod installed to the sdcard.

Then I started playing with different ROMs on the internet. At some point I also flashed the device with another GENERIC Stock ROM for this device. At this point, the generic Stock ROM permanently changed my static boot logo and the boot animation. Originally it was a static Huawei logo with Vodafone animation (Red Vodafone logo). That was replaced by the static Huawei logo AND Huawei generic boot animation. 
This is the problem as:

```
1. I need to replace with the original static boot logo and boot animation in the event of a warranty claim. 
2. I need the assurance that recovering to the stock ROM backup will restore everything to the way it was except the bootlogo and boot animation.
```

Now if I revert to the stock ROM from the backup (via ClockWorkMod recovery), everything from the backup is restored EXCEPT for the static boot logo and the boot animation sequence.

Things I have tried:
1. From the installed terminal, as su: I tried copying the recovery.img from the backup to the root of the sdcard. Then as su, I executed the following command:

```
flash_image recovery /sdcard/recovery.img
```

The above command worked. I rebooted into recovery. Then I rebooted again but still am seeing the generic static Huawei boot logo and boot animation.

I can see the following files from my stock rom backup:

```
.android_secure.vfat.tar
boot.img
cache.yaffs2.img
data.yaffs2.img
nandroid.md5
recovery.img   ---> This is the file I copied to the root of the sdcard.
system.yaffs2.img
```

I have also tried asking in other forums to get the copy of the boot animation from the stock ROM with no success.

Questions:

1. Do I have the original boot logo and boot animation from stock rom backup (above file     list)?
2. If so, is there a way to recover it? If not: is there a known source to get the original boot animation?

Answer (score 2):

There are two locations where boot animation files could be stored: `/data/local` and `/system/media`.

http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-change-customize-create-android-boot-animation-guide/